# Blazor Hybrid MAUI - Out of Memory

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, blazor, maui

We have a Blazor Hybrid MAUI app that runs great for an hour so, then all of a sudden, quite consistently every 2-3 hours we get the Out of Memory error see attached image. You can hit refresh and the app works again. The same app works great in PWA/Browser mode. What is the best way to troubleshoot this? .NET 8 p6.

[image]

Comment: Please provide more information. I could tell you ten different possible reasons with the information you provided.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @AztecCodes - the problem is that I am not sure what information to provide. The app is working great in the browser. Also, I am running the exact same app in a dev environment without getting this crash.

Comment: I don't know how many GBs of RAM in your device, however, GC(Garbage collection) should have kept it down to a manageable number and there're many factors contributing to the run out of memory like [Recursive rendering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-7.0#recursive-rendering)...You may check [Debug a memory leak](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/debug-memory-leak) on how to debug it. Hope that helps.

Comment: Rolled back to .NET 7 and the issue gone.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Looks like there could be a potential issue when using .NET 8.